# On designing a MAIL-API for haskell

Tags: haskell

I was wondering if it would be a good idea to design an abstract MAIL-API for haskell. The API would basically be designed as an (tagless) EDSL.

MAIL API terms could then be "evaluated" with a switchable interpreter. These interpreters could then make use of a particular and already existing library.

Someone in need of MAIL would then not have to tie himself to a particular mail library but would instead code against the MAIL-API, ie. build terms in the EDSL and defer the choice of evaluator.

Günther

Comment: What do you main by "MAIL API"? Do you mean an API to represent access to an `mbox`-style mail/mail-repository (RFC 4155)? Or do you want to speak SMTP?

Comment: Actually I meant an email client library. For Pop3, IMAP, SMTP clients. But defering the details of implementation, thus technically merely an API.

Comment: Like the JavaMail API but for Haskell, right?

Answer (score 3):

I've created a [special interest group for email](http://www.haskellers.com/teams/1/) on Haskellers.com. I would recommend that we move the discussion for this topic over there.

Regarding this topic: I'm not sure how abstract an API you're talking here. Do you mean to abstract away sending/receiving of messages? Parsing and rendering? The former seems possible, the latter impossible. But I'm not sure how much of a benefit will be attained from any sort of abstraction.

Comment: Hi Michael, good idea and thank you for starting the SIG. I haven't figured out yet how to post on the page. Could you gimme a hint?

Comment: Go to the discussions section first. You'll need to be logged in.